# BZR checkout from remote to local

Tags: bazaar

I have a directory named "SAMPLE" for version control located in the remote server, How can I checkout "SAMPLE" to a specific directory in my local computer?

Comment: Is your trouble formulating the URL to use when you checkout? Or is your trouble doing a checkout to a specific local directory? (Or both?) Do you prefer the command line or Bazaar Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you access files on your remote server (ftp, sftp, ssh, http, etc.).

Generally, you would use either `bzr branch` or `bzr checkout` to get a copy. `bzr branch` will allow you to perform local commits and only push them to the remote server when you're satisfied, while `bzr checkout` will directly commit to the remote server. You can use `bzr unbind` and `bzr bind` to convert between checkouts and branches.

For example, assuming that you have the SAMPLE directory on the remote server in your home directory, that the server is named `server.com`, and use sftp to access it, you can use one of:

```
bzr branch sftp://server.com/~/SAMPLE MYSAMPLE
bzr checkout sftp://server.com/~/SAMPLE MYSAMPLE
```

to obtain a local copy in the MYSAMPLE subdirectory of your current directory (obviously, you can specify a different directory name for the destination, too.

If you don't use sftp, you can consult `bzr help urlspec` to find out what other prefixes are available.

If the file isn't in your home directory, but uses an absolute path, you will have to insert that instead, as in the following examples:

```
bzr branch sftp://server.com/path/to/SAMPLE MYSAMPLE
bzr checkout sftp://server.com/path/to/SAMPLE MYSAMPLE
bzr branch http://server.com/path/to/SAMPLE MYSAMPLE
bzr checkout http://server.com/path/to/SAMPLE MYSAMPLE
```

If you need more information about the difference between the `branch` and `checkout` commands, `bzr help branch` and `bzr help checkout` should tell you what you need.

Comment: You're correct with respect to checkouts vs. branches, I will edit my response accordingly. With respect to `bzr+ssh`, that's basically another URL scheme explained in `bzr help urlspec`. Installing `bzr` remotely to support it (if it isn't already) would be a different question.

Comment: @janos thanks for bzr+ssh tips... usually i'm using sftp which stuck most of time